# mysql creates duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

Im just beginner and a cant understand why my code generates same identical rows after inserting it. please help me.
here is my html code:

```
<form id="sing" action="signup.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="სახელი"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="მომხმარებელი"> <br>
    <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="პაროლი"> <br>
    <button type="submit">რეგისტრაცია</button>
</form>
```

php:

```
include 'dbh.php';

$first = $_POST['first'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO user (first, uid, pwd) 
VALUES ('$first', '$uid', '$pwd')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "maica joo";
} else {
    echo "kaia";
}
```

Comment: it creates 2 identical row

Answer (score 1):

That's because `mysqli_query($conn, $sql)` is called twice, change the code to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "maica joo";
} else {
    echo "kaia";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are running `mysqli_query()` twice!! So it creates 2 identical rows.

```
// first time it insert a row
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// now you run it again and it creates that row again
if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "maica joo";
} else {
    echo "kaia";
}
```

Amend this to

```
// first time it insert a row
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// now test $result to see if the query failed
if (!$result) {
    echo "maica joo";
} else {
    echo "kaia";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running the query twice with the two `mysqli_query`.

Change it to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$result) {
```